Invertibility between generalized and actual coordinates
Chapter $1$, page $13$ of Classical Mechanics by Goldstein ($2^{nd}$ edition), he states the following after defining a transformation equation:

"It is always assumed that one can transform back from the ($q_i$) set to the ($r_i$)set, i.e the transformation equation combined with the constraint equation can be inverted to obtain $q_i$ as a function of $r_i$ and $t$."

For a relation to be invertible, there are two necessary and sufficient conditions:

The relation is one-to-one and onto.
The Jacobian determinant is non-singular.

i.e.
$$(q_1, q_2, ..., q_{3N-k}) \mapsto (r_1(q_1,q_2,...,q_{3N-k}),r_2(q_1,q_2,...,q_{3N-k}),...,r_N(q_1,q_2,...,q_{3N-k}))$$
and the associated Jacobian matrix has a determinant non-zero.
Case $I$
: A particle moving on the surface of the sphere. One can use three cartesian coordinates to describe the particle's motion, say $x_1,x_2,x_3$. However, we know that only two degrees of freedom exist due to the constraint. Say we use the following coordinates, $r_1,r_2$ (radius of sphere and angle).
So, a transformation relation will be of the form...
$$ (r_1,r_2) \mapsto (x_1(r_1,r_2), x_2(r_1,r_2), x_3(r_1,r_2)). $$
Since this relation is not bijective, the inverse is not possible. Or, the Jacobian Matrix will not be square, so the determinant is out of the question.
Takeaway: If the system can be reduced to a smaller number of coordinates, the relation will no longer be bijective and, hence, not invertible.
Question: How can one justify the initial claim made by Goldstein? I would greatly appreciate it if the answer involved an argument related to the Jacobian transformation.

The quote (v2) is truncated/incomplete and seems to misrepresents the actual statement in Goldstein. Please include relevant parts.

I have edited the quote by including relevant part.

While it is true that you use 3 numbers for Cartesian coordinates, you do not use the full set of triplets. You use the subset that satisfies $x_1^2 +x_2^2 + x_3^2 = r^2$. This subset has two degrees of freedom. There is a bijection onto $q_1$ and $q_2$.
There is also a bijection from the full set of Cartesian coordinates onto the full set of spherical coordinates.

Thank you sir, how do we present the argument in the language of jacobians?
